# Hyper-V - main drive is running .avhd snapshot rather than .vhd main drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I have a 2008 HYPER-V host crash on me last night.  Now as I am trying to restore the VM it looks like the XML file is pointing to the .avhd snapshot as the primary drive.  Not sure how long this has been happening, but how would I restore this VM?  The .avhd file is about 120GB - the same size as the server should be.  I tried merging the parent disk and the snapshot and got an error about "invalid paths".  I'm going to try re-creating the old folder structure and see i that works.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to merge those files? Using hyper-V menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're main drive is actually .avhd but just that you had snapshot so you have .vhd and a differencing snapshot now. You have to merge them now. If merging them doesn't work automatically try using manual [hyper-v snapshot](http://itproctology.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-manually-merge-hyper-v-snapshots.html) merge.